# TFS Service GIT, Users cant see my "published" branch locally

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Wondering if someone has an idea of whats wrong. I created a local branch called "refactor" I wanted a peer to look at the changes so I "published" the branch in visual studio 2013. Looking at the tfs website I can see that we all have inherited access to that branch. We can all see it in the explorer on the tfs service website. However in visual studio he can only see master and one of his local branches which he also tried publishing but I can not see either. I know its hard to guess without being able to see whats happening but I was hoping someone might have some ideas on where to look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the [tfs git pull](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/pull-vs-git.aspx) only update your existing local branches with the commits from origin/same branches.

Try:

- a fetch (to be sure to bring *all* origin branches)
- making a new branch from one of the origin branches

If the IDE doesn't let you that, fall back to the CLI 5command Line Interface).
For instance, after a fetch, your colleague could do a:

```
git checkout --track -b refactor origin/refactor
```

Comment: I had no idea what you said initially but now that im more familiar with GIT I see what you mean :) so yes checking out the origin/refactor branch with tracking was what I was missing.